# Make Closure Compiler strip log function usages

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a logging API I want to expose to some internal JS code. I want to be able to use this API to log, but only when I am making a debug build. Right now, I have it partially working. It only logs on debug builds, but the calls to this API are still in the code when there is a regular build. I would like the closure-compiler to remove this essentially dead code when I compiler with goog.DEBUG = false.

Log definition:

```
goog.provide('com.foo.android.Log');
com.foo.Log.e = function(message){
    goog.DEBUG && AndroidLog.e(message);
}
goog.export(com.foo.Log, "e", com.foo.Log.e);
```

AndroidLog is a Java object provided to the webview this will run in, and properly externed like this:

```
var AndroidLog = {};

/**
 * Log out to the error console
 * 
 * @param {string} message The message to log
 */
AndroidLog.e = function(message) {};
```

Then, in my code, I can use:

```
com.foo.Log.e("Hello!"); // I want these stripped in production builds
```

My question is this: How can I provide this API, use this API all over my code, but then have any calls to this API removed when not compiled with goog.DEBUG = true? Right now, my code base is getting bloated with a bunch of calls to the Log API that are never called. I want the removed.

Thanks!

Comment: OK, after some further digging, it appears that externed functions are not inlined. http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=230

I would still like to find a workaround other than prepending every call with goog.DEBUG &&

Comment: I wrote a small script myself in Python to strip all my debug msgs out of the source as part of my build process.  I could find something when I needed it either.  It's odd because it should be such a common need.

Comment: Yes, it's the last line in the first code block. This is probably what's getting me in trouble, huh?

Comment: Put `if (!goog.DEBUG) AndroidLog.e = function() {};` at the beginning of your code?  Notice that if you export `com.foo.Log.e`, the compiler won't remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turns out this is easy to do if I stop exporting com.foo.Log() and its methods. If I really want to be able to log in some specific cases, but still strip out the log calls in my internal code, I can just declare two classes for this:

```
// This will get inlined and stripped, since its not exported.
goog.provide('com.foo.android.Log');
com.foo.Log.e = function(message){
    goog.DEBUG && AndroidLog.e(message);
}
// Don't export.


// This be available to use after closure compiler runs, since it's exported.
goog.provide('com.foo.android.production.Log');
goog.exportSymbol("ProductionLog", com.foo.android.production.Log);
com.foo.android.production.Log.log = function(message){
    goog.DEBUG && AndroidLog.e(message);
}
// Export.
goog.exportProperty(com.foo.android.production.Log, "log", com.foo.android.production.Log.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Closure Compiler provides four options in [CompilerOptions.java](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.java) to strip code: 1) `stripTypes`, 2) `stripNameSuffixes`, 3) `stripNamePrefixes` and 4) `stripTypePrefixes`.   The Closure build tool *plovr*, exposes `stripNameSuffixes` and `stripTypePrefixes` through its JSON [configuration file options](http://plovr.com/options) `name-suffixes-to-strip` and `type-prefixes-to-strip`.

There are excellent examples of how these options work in *Closure: The Definitive Guide* on pages 442 to 444. The following lines are provided as common use cases:

```
options.stripTypePrefixes = ImmutableSet.of(“goog.debug”, “goog.asserts”);
options.stripNameSuffixes = ImmutableSet.of(“logger”, “logger_”);
```

To understand the nuances of these options and avoid potential pitfalls, I highly recommend reading the complete examples in *Closure: The Definitive Guide*.

Comment: Thanks! I should mention that I'm using the Closure Ant Task, and so don't have the ability to pass compiler options in directly. I was contemplating subclassing the ant task in order to pass in my own compiler options, but wanted to ask first if there was in fact a way to do this. I'll take a look at plovr as well.

Comment: @SkyKelsey: The Compiler options mentioned above to strip code are internal to the Closure Compiler Java source, namely CompilerOptions.java. However, plovr makes it easy to use stripNameSuffixes and stripTypePrefixes without writing Java code. I'm currently writing a suite of Ant tasks for all of the Closure Tools that will provide added flexibility. Hopefully they will be ready for release before the end of April 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running your own script as jfriend00 suggested I would look at the define api of the compiler (which is where goog.DEBUG comes from as well), you have DEBUG, COMPILED by default, but there you can roll your own.

Comment: This misses the point.  The point isn't to just turn off the debug output (that's easy).  The point is to remove all the debug code before deployment so it's not taking extra space, executing or even being shown to the world.

Comment: lennel, thanks for the suggestion. As jfriend00 mentioned, that will simply allow me to pass data in. I'm already using data passed in via the goog.DEBUG parameter, and it's stripping the body of a function perfectly. But that blank function body is never inlined into my code to remove the function usages. I think this is because CC can't assume that externed functions will not be modified at run-time?

Comment: sorry, been away on holiday. If you compile with a define variable set to false,  the compiler will omit that code in advanced mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified a compiler and packaged it as an npm package.

You can get it here: https://github.com/thanpolas/superstartup-closure-compiler#readme

It will strip all logging messages during compilation